# Conflicting Laravel controllers- one can call method the other gives non-static error

Tags: laravel-5.4

I've taken over the code from another developer, and I'm quite confused and stuck: one controller I can call the class method `CLASSS::method` perfectly OK. the other Controller has a copy of the orginal code and modified. On the second one, I get the "non-static method" error.

**Call Chain:**
`Controller->Class->filtered results->Controller response`

**1A) (Working) Conttroller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\V1;

use App\Site as SiteClass;
use Facades\App\Site;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\{
    Http\Controllers\Controller,
    Http\Requests\SiteRequest,
    Helper\ResourceTrait,
    Assets,
    Alerts,
    Licensee,
    Permits,
    LandOwner,
    Utility
};
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    private $obj;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->obj = new SiteClass();
    }


    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        try
        {

            $data = Site::filter(
                ($request->has('sort')? $request->input('sort') : ''),
                ($request->has('filter')? $request->input('filter') : '')
                );

      ...removed some extra code that's not relevant ...

            return response($data);

        }
        catch(\Exception $e)
        {
        Log::info('Create exception from here?' . $e);
            return response(array('error'=>$e->getMessage()),422);
        }

    }  // index

    ....
}
```

**1B) (Working) Class**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use \App\BaseModel;

class Site extends BaseModel
{
    protected $table = 'sites';

    protected $fillable = [
      "status","structureType","siteId","name","coverage","address","postCode", "subdistrict", "district", "region", "state", "country", "localCouncil", "latitude", "longitude", "dimensions",
    "siteHandover", "startBilling", "utilityBillAcct", "utilityBillingAddress", "renewalTerm",
    "capex", "opex", "siteManager", "siteManagerPhone", "siteManagerEmail", "siteOwnerManager", "siteOwnerManagerPhone", "siteOwnerManagerEmail"
    ];

    ...
    // Working Static method call.
    public function filter($sort = null, $search = null)
    {
        $data = $this;

        // check if search variable not empty
        if ($search != null)
        {
            $data = $data->where(function ($query) use ($search){
                return $query->where($this->table.'.name','like','%'.$search.'%')
                    ->orWhere($this->table.'.status','=',$search)
                    ->orWhere($this->table.'.siteId','like','%'.$search.'%')
                    ->orWhere($this->table.'.address','like','%'.$search.'%')
                    ->orWhere($this->table.'.subdistrict','like','%'.$search.'%')
                    ->orWhere($this->table.'.district','like','%'.$search.'%')
                    ->orWhere($this->table.'.region','like','%'.$search.'%')
                    ->orWhere($this->table.'.state','like','%'.$search.'%')
                    ->orWhere($this->table.'.country','like','%'.$search.'%')
                    ->orWhere($this->table.'.localCouncil','like','%'.$search.'%')
                    ;
            });

             if ($sort != null)
                {
                $sorts = explode('|', $sort);

                $data = $data->orderBy($sorts[0],$sorts[1]);
                }

        }

        // check if sort variable not empty
        if ($sort != null)
        {
            $sorts = explode('|', $sort);

            $data = $data->orderBy($sorts[0],$sorts[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = $data->orderBy('siteId','desc');
        }

        // return data
        return $data->paginate(Config::get('api.records'));
    }

}
```

**2A) (Failing) Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\V1;

use App\{
    Http\Controllers\Controller,
    Helper\ResourceTrait,
    Http\Requests\OrganisationRequest,
    Organisation
};


use Illuminate\{
    Http\Request,
    Support\Facades\Config,
        Support\Facades\Log
};

class OrganisationController extends Controller
{
    private $org;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->org = new Organisation();
    }


    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        try
        {
            //WORKAROUND: $this->org->... works
            $data = Organisation::filter(
                ($request->has('sort')? $request->input('sort') : ''),
                ($request->has('filter')? $request->input('filter') : '')
                );   // FAILS with non-static method call error

            return response($data);

        }
        catch(\Exception $e)
        {
            return response(array('error'=>$e->getMessage()),422);
        }

    }  // index
}
```

...

**2B) Failing Class**

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

use \App\BaseModel;

class Organisation extends BaseModel
{

protected $table = 'organisation';

public function filter($sort = null, $search = null)
    {
        $data = $this;

        // check if search variable not empty
        if ($search != null)
        {
            $data = $data->where(function ($query) use ($search){
                return $query->where($this->table.'.name','like','%'.$search.'%')
                    ;
            });

             if ($sort != null)
                {
                $sorts = explode('|', $sort);

                $data = $data->orderBy($sorts[0],$sorts[1]);
                }

        }

        // check if sort variable not empty
        if ($sort != null)
        {
            $sorts = explode('|', $sort);

            $data = $data->orderBy($sorts[0],$sorts[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = $data->orderBy('name');
        }

        // return data
        return $data->paginate(Config::get('api.records'));
    }

}
```

To my untutored eye, they look identical, yet one works and the other doesn't. Apologies in advance for the volume of code, but I don't know which parts are affecting what. I suspect it's somethng to do with an imported class, but I'm lost frankly :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Site` has a [Facade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/facades) while `Organisation` does not.

Facades (from the docs) provide a "static" interface to classes that are available in the application's service container.

Comment: Fantastic! That solved it. Thanks, still learning Larvel etc.